# htaccess redirect to domain based on string in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

We have a site where content is generated from CMS. The issue is people have added links to their website without the `http://` hence all the links got generated in a wrong way.

for eg:     http://www.example.com/ec/shefaliaxena/eventupdate/www.shefalisaxena.com

What I would like to do is get the data after last slash and check if it is valid domain using regex and if it is valid domain then redirect it to that domain or else do nothing.

I was able to extract the data after last slash using regex (`[^/]+$`) but wondering how do I acheieve this redirect.

I could do this easily with the coding but I would like to handle this from `.htaccess` file itself so that it doesn't add burden on the server.

Comment: Did you try the obvious? `RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ http://$1/ [L,NC,R=301]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did tried that but this rule redirects all the request, I just want to redirect only those request where after the last slash if there is a valid domain. If it is not a valid domain then it should simply move forward and should not do anything.

Comment: You'd need to determine exactly what kinds of domains are used there in order to create a good expression for it. That said, how are you outputting the website URLs in the browser? You could always do some sort of check to see if `http://` exists and, if it doesn't, add it before showing the URL on the page. Doing it this way is probably best as you won't need a redirect at all.

Comment: can you share some example if you can on this any.

Comment: I don't know how your links are generated. [This answer](/a/2762083/1626250) may point you in the right direction. Once you have added the prefix, you can echo the URL on your page.

Comment: The links are generated exactly the way i had mentioned in my question http://www.example.com/ec/shefaliaxena/eventupdate/www.shefalisaxena.com or at times they are without www. Normally they are without the protocol like http or https

Comment: What I'm saying is that I don't know exactly how you are putting the links in your page. I couldn't give you an example of what to do because I can't see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem you might run into trying to do this is that valid filenames often look a lot like valid domain names, so you'll want to make sure something that looks like a domain name isn't a valid file before trying to forward the URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /(([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6})$ http://$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

If you're generating the URLs from data users have entered, I'd definitely look at adding the protocol there instead of doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks Kevin that really helped and sorted my problem. Kudos to you.